# How to configure Spring WebSocket in cluster

Tags: spring, cluster-computing, spring-websocket

I have configured Spring Websocket over Stomp in my project.

My enviroment have 2 cluster node and one balancer. 
How can configure the spring websocket in cluster mode?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use message broker like ActiveMQ / RabbitMQ etc. Either you can set a seperate node for message broker or you can also set it on any node in your 2 cluster node.

Next thing you  need to configure enableStompBrokerRelay in your WebSocketConfig on both nodes.

```
  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic","/queue").setRelayHost("MQHOSTNAME").setRelayPort(MQPORT);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm using Weblogic server 12.1.3. Can I use your approach in this application server?

Comment: I have tested it on tomcat, though it will work on weblogic too.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WLPRG/websockets.htm#WLPRG805 for weblogic 12.1.3